# Whether iPad 4.3 simulator is supporting UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert or not?

Tags: ipad, uikeyboard, appearance

I have used this code:

```
myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
myTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```

But when I run my project in iPad simulator 4.3, keyboard appearance is not getting changed?

It looks like the same as UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault one

The same code for iPhone 4.3 works fine. Keyboard appearance is getting changed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert mode is meant for input in alert view, for important things. It has probably a different behavior. Apple uses it for example in the App/iTunes/iBookstore Store login screen.

Indeed, on the iPad, the appearance is the same.

I think that Apple recommends against using the alert mode.

Comment: Is there any link available where apple says this? Because of this, my application looks different for both the devices (iPhone and iPad). Is there any other way to use UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert into our code?

Comment: I think I heard this at the WWDC. I'm not sure which year (since 2008). By the way, the doc page for `UITextInputTraits` explains it too.